# GET request with illegal character in Java

Tags: java, encoding, httpclient, feign

I'm trying to create a GET call in Java on an API with a path variable containing an illegal character.

```
GET http://api.example.com/key/foo<bar
```

The path contains the character `<`. The HTTP client encodes it as %3C but I need to keep it as `<`, because API server don't decode it.

I have to do this call, and the API provider doesn't want to change anything to be more compliant.

Calling the GET request with illegal character works with Postman.
I'm trying to do it in Java now.

I've tried with Feign, HttpClient, WebClient and OkHttp, I don't find a way to do it.

Do you know a Java Http client that will allow me to do it ? Or the proper encoding option for the clients above ?

I've tried to create a RequestInterceptor with Feign to update uri, but it works only for some characters, as defined in RFC 6570, but not for `<`, which is re-replaced with %3C after my replacement.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you will find some HTTP library that allows you to send improper requests. You could however use TCP sockets directly, then implement your own version of HTTP that does not escape these characters.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right :/